# What are the most popular IDEs per language?

Tags: programming-languages, ide

This has nothing to do with having a favourite editor or anything like that. I was just wondering, per language, what are the most popular Integrated Development Environments? Maybe a top 2-3 if there is some contention. (Perceived popularity is enough)

Thus Far:

**C#** - Visual Studio, SharpDevelop

**Java** - Eclipse, NetBeans, IDEA

**Objective-C** - Xcode

**Delphi** - RAD Studio

**Object Pascal** - Delphi, Lazarus

**C, C++** - Visual Studio, Vim

**PL/SQL** - RapidSQL, Oracle SQLDeveloper

**PHP** - Eclipse, NetBeans, Nusphere PHPed

**Actionscript (AS2, AS3)** - FlashDevelop

**Flex** - Flash Builder 4

**Python** - Eclipse, IDLE

**Perl** - Padre

**Common Lisp** - Lispworks, Emacs

**Ruby** - TextMate

**Haskell** - Vim

**Fortran** - Vim

**Visual Basic** - Visual Studio

Comment: Is this a bit too broad?

Comment: @Jim, why too broad?  Just a question that **lists** IDEs, not compares and describes them.

Comment: @Jim Leonardo: Pavel Shved is right. There's no comparison, I leave it up to future readers to make the ultimate decision of what to use. Assuming that many others in the past have weighed the pros and cons, and then chosen, I'm hoping that the popularity of the IDEs listed here will reflect a culmination of individual independent research. I am well aware, however, that this won't be accurate in 100% of the cases.

Comment: The problem I have with this....I can tell you what IDEs I use (Visual Studio, Eclipse, multiple terminals with vim/g++/gdb executions), but not what's most popular.

Comment: One way to treat this question would be to list one language/IDE pair per answer and let the # of upvotes gauge popularity.

Comment: If this is going to become a voting thing it should be Community Wiki

Comment: I was asking if it was too broad in large part because someone looking for an idea on what IDE to use with a particular language might have a hard time finding this question and its answers. I was asking the question because it occurred to me to ask... not because I had strong feelings. (so it really was a question, not a critique disguised as a question).

Comment: I think that the proper name for "the Delphi IDE" is "RAD Studio".

Comment: I agree that this should be community-wiki, [not because it's a poll](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8/purpose-of-community-wiki/), but just because it's broad enough that it wouldn't make sense to have multiple answers for each language, so anyone should be able to edit them.

Comment: And technically the proper name for the language is "Object Pascal" (Delphi was the IDE), although a friend and apparently some professionals like Mason below still call it "Delphi".

Comment: Is VIM an IDE? That's not a sarcastic comment - I really want to know.

Comment: Community wiki or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments) :-)

Comment: This is not a poll. It's a discovery. Which is good and valuable.

Answer (score 18):

**All languages** - [VIM](http://www.vim.org/)

I don't like IDE's.

If I'm on OSX I'll use TextMate at time, but mostly I do everything (JavaScript, Java, Python, PHP) in VIM. I'm also quicker then several colleagues who use an IntelliJ.

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed it didn't say emacs, but +1 nevertheless. ^^

Comment: It asks what are the most popular IDEs, not which one you use.

Comment: @Andrew: Half the Zend dev team uses VIM. I doubt it's "unpopular" by any stretch.

Comment: Can do you debugging from VIM, is that possible?

Comment: @Jon: Sure, and the perl debugger can even drive plain old vi, the real one, that Keith Bostic wrote.

Comment: @Josh [citation needed], or rather, would be nice, for "Half the Zend dev team uses VIM."

Comment: @Yaser: This isn't Wikipedia. I don't remember where I heard that, could have been the PHP mailing list or one of any number of blogs. If I run across the source I'll post it.

Comment: Although I enjoy emacs minor modes for languages with compiled REPLs (Erlang and Haskell, especially), I prefer vim for everything else.

Comment: You're obviously very skilled at using vim, but are your slower colleagues as skilled at using IntelliJ? Most people use less than 10% of the functionality of their IDE.

Comment: @Joeri: Considering the people, no. If they were forced to use the keyboard more they might be.

Comment: Vico http://www.vicoapp.com/ TextMate meets Vi, can I see a smile?

Comment: Id wager if we stuck the OP infront of an IDE they would see gains. Just because musashi used bokken to fight opponents doesnt mean it was optimal.

Comment: @Yablargo People have been telling me that for years, and I've tried IDEs. No noticeable gains or improvements.

Comment: Just based on the auto-complete humps I can't imagine I could go any quicker without. I guess it boils down to what languages you are using. With a very verbose set of namespace e.g C#/Java lots of characters get saved that would be kinda tedious I would imagine

Answer (score 13):

Java - IDEA, Eclipse, NetBeans.

Comment: In that order? If so, do you have a source? I would have thought it was Eclipse, NetBeans, IDEA or NetBeans, Eclipse, IDEA...

Comment: Netbeans is part of oracle whereas the others are not so I would assume netbeans would be the better of the 3 although I do prefer eclipse to netbeans.

Comment: to my understanding Eclipse is the most popular for Java itself.

Comment: Although I prefer netbeans, but I primarily use PHP

Comment: Remember, the order isn't necessarily important - it's more of the 'major players' if you will. And given that perceived popularity is all that matters in this instance... order, again, isn't important.

Comment: @SnOrfus: Yes, I know, I was merely curious whether talonx meant to list them in order of popularity. If he did, I might have to give IDEA a try.

Comment: @Chinmay Kanchi: Then I consider this question a success already!

Comment: @Chinmay - I listed them in order of my personal preference :) In fact, I would always prefer IDEA over the others.

Comment: Walter's right: Eclipse is probably the most popular. IntelliJ IDEA is the [best one](https://twitter.com/rc_dickerson/status/22537374074) though. :-)

Comment: @Chinmay - It's true that once you become used to an IDE, trying out anything else is painful. But you should definitely give IDEA a try.

Comment: @talonx: I don't do enough Java for that to be an issue. I might do some major Java stuff in a few months though, and at that point, I'll give IDEA a try...

Comment: It doesn't have to be Java only, see my comment [at the bottom of this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6847/whats-your-favorite-programming-language/6850#6850).

Answer (score 10):

### Ruby

There's [a question in the Hampton's Ruby Survey](http://survey.hamptoncatlin.com/survey/stats#question_6) that may provide some concrete numbers about the "text editor" of preference in the Ruby world. Here's a chart of the results (*at the time of writing*):

[image: A chart of the results for the "text editor of preference" question of the Hampton's Ruby Survey]

The results suggest that **TextMate** is the most popular text editor among Ruby developers. It is worth noting that TextMate's popularity seems to be declining; so is the popularity of Eclipse based editors. On the other hand, the popularity of Vim, which I personally use, seems to be increasing.

Comment: +1 Nice graph, much quicker to parse than the source page

Comment: Vim is gaining! More power to the engines, don't let them get away!

Answer (score 6):

**Objective-C** - Xcode

Comment: What else can you write Obj-C in?!

Comment: Is that a question or just rhetorical?

Comment: @Alex: ProjectCenter and ProjectManager under GNUstep, TextEdit under OpenStep, and emacs on pretty much anything all have Objective-C syntax support. There's a stillborn project to do Objective-C for Eclipse, which failed because the CDT didn't support ObjC.

Comment: Syntax support doesn't make for an IDE; it's necessary but not sufficient. I was quite curious to see if there were any other full-fledged IDEs for Obj-C; sounds like there may not be, yet.

Comment: Objective-C does exist besides Mac doesnt it?  As such, I'd think that its Cocoa that is so tightly coupled so Xcode, not necessarily Objective-C.  I'm kind of conjecturing tho, I am not a serious Objective-C coder by any means.

Comment: @jon_darkstar: It does, but I'd still say that Xcode is the most popular IDE for Objective-C.

Comment: id agree that its easily the most popular.  i was responding to Alex saying 'what else can you write Obj-C in' and got bunch of upvotes.  i dont know what those other IDEs are, but they exist

Comment: JetBrains AppCode http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/

Answer (score 5):

For Delphi, the Delphi IDE.

Comment: I don't recall there being a choice ;-)  But I wish there was (at least for Delphi 7)  Whoops, there go my blue dots, time to restart.

Comment: @Peter: Well, there's always Lazarus... :P

Comment: *Technically* Objective Pascal... Blue dots?

Comment: @Mark C: Dots in the gutter at the side of the editor that indicate where lines of executable code are. They show where the debugger will stop when you're tracing through the code, and where the valid lines to set breakpoints on are.  There were some glitches in earlier IDEs that could break this functionality, though.

Answer (score 4):

**Common Lisp**

Commercially, probably LispWorks.

Outside of the commercial implementations, almost certainly EMACS + SLIME

Answer (score 4):

**C++**: Visual Studio with Visual Assist X

Answer (score 3):

**Java - Eclipse** (Java EE, with Google App Eng, and GWT, and Plug-in for Version Control)

**C++ - EMacs/Eclipse/GEdit**

GEdit does a pretty good just at color coding most languages.

Answer (score 3):

**Erlang** - Emacs

Answer (score 3):

**C** --- Emacs

Answer (score 3):

Everyone I know working with Python uses Emacs or Vim.

Comment: I use PyDev, but then I'm really working with Jython.

Answer (score 3):

For both **Perl** and **Python**: *Emacs* and *Vim*. Beats Eclipse in terms of popularity.

Answer (score 2):

**Visual Basic** - Visual Studio
**C++, Fortran** - Visual Studio, Vim, Emacs

Comment: Are you saying that Vim,Emacs are among the most popular IDEs for C#? I somehow doubt that.

Comment: I agree with vim about C++ definitely not C#. For c# there's visual studio and you can't really get anything better imho.

Comment: How could you list vim and emacs for C# and C++ and not for Python. I would have thought more Python programmers use them than C# programmers.

Comment: @JohnFx - You're right. An error on my part.

Comment: @Chinmay Kanchi - An error on my part in regard to C#. As for Python, I had a feeling these are more used.

Comment: @Rook: What about Eclipse CDT for C++?

Comment: @Chinmay - don't know. Most people I come in contact with use one of those two on *nix, or VS on Windows. This is of course subjective, but so is the question. If you want I can add it, but then you're the one defending it :)

Comment: @Rook: Fair enough ;)

Answer (score 2):

For PHP there is also Nusphere PHPed which is absolutely great, not free but one of the best. I used to use it all the time.

For Haskell I would say vim,and that probably goes for C too.

Answer (score 2):

**Object Pascal** - Delphi, Lazarus

**C,C++** - Bloodshed Dev C++ , Visual Studio 2008 C++

**PL/SQL** - RapidSQL (by Embarcadero), Oracle SQLDeveloper

**C#** - Visual Studio (Currently in 2008, but 2010 looks sweet when I upgrade!)

Comment: For the record, Dev-C++ is more than a little out of date. It includes MinGW-GCC **3.4**, while the current release of MinGW-GCC is **4.5**. wxDev-C++ supposedly comes with a more recent compiler, although I would say there are fer better alternatives.

Comment: ---> CodeBlocks

Answer (score 1):

**Java** - Eclipse, NetBeans

**Python** - IDLE? (Ships by default, don't know about popularity)

**Perl** - Padre

Comment: Why would anyone ever want any other IDE than vi for perl?

Comment: @tchrist: The fact that it was made from scratch to be an IDE for perl indicates that there are people who want it

Comment: That doesn’t answer my question. *Why* would they want it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I would say that the most popular in Python is Eclipse + pyDev

Everyone Ruby programmer I know uses TextMate in MacOS

Comment: What about non-Mac Ruby programmers?

Comment: Curiously, any Rubist I know is absolutely a Mac fan! (and uses also vi when they have to use other machines)

Answer (score 1):

Was never really a fan of an IDE and find I learn the language better without the assistance.  VIM was mentioned but at times I really am not interested in VIM and would rather use nano.

[Nano Editor](http://www.nano-editor.org/)

Answer (score 1):

### PHP

**Actual PHP programming**  - Netbeans (PHP version) or Eclipse (PHP Development Tools)
**PHP Templating**  - Dreamweaver

Note - By actual PHP programing I mean (for example) OOP using frameworks like CakePHP, Symfony or CodeIgniter.
By templating I mean using simple PHP for including headers/footers or formatting.

Comment: Netbeans also has a nice Vim plug-in I hear, for those of you who love vim.  I've never used it myself

Comment: I started using Eclipse for Java, but was initially reluctant to use it for PHP.  I've since been quite happy with it, especially for Drupal development.

Comment: I also see Komodo appear frequently in IDE discussion in the Drupal community.

Comment: "PHP Eclipse" would be more accurate then "Eclipse", the PHP Eclipse package includes all the tool you need to develop PHP.

Comment: @HoLtView  Made the change,

Comment: I use the PHP version of Netbeans myself.  IMHO I find it has more usefull features than Eclipse's version.  
  
PHP in Dreamweaver CS5 has improved, finally. Not really great but works ok if you're primarily dealing with HTML/CSS

Comment: @GApple I've never used Komodo myself, maybe I'll give it a try.

Comment: Why does this keep getting down voted?

Comment: Because PHP is such a gangsta language.

Comment: You can do 'actual PHP programming' without using frameworks (some would argue in fact that you can't do it *with* frameworks), and/or without OOP, and I think that your answer could come across as elitist. That might be why some people have downvoted you.

Comment: @Alan.  that was meant as more of an example.  There is a difference between templating and actual programming, that is more of what I meant.

Comment: PHPEd is, by far, the best php ide. Komodo and eclipse are toys in comparison. Netbeans is okay.

Answer (score 1):

**Actionscript(AS2,AS3)** - FlashDevelop

Answer (score 1):

[JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/) has IDE's for several languages that have a similar look & feel:

IntelliJ IDEA for Java

RubyMine for Ruby and Ruby on Rails

PHPStorm for PHP, HTML and JavaScript

PyCharm for Python and Django

(I have the last three.)

Answer (score 1):

C++ - code::blocks

Comment: I belive Code::Blocks is one of the best IDEs for C++, however, it's kinda struggling with acceptance. It won't beat VisualStudio on Windows. However, with declining popularity of Eclipse, Code::Blocks might get another chance.

Answer (score 1):

One IDE that has been forgotten: **[Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/)** - Eclipse based IDE for PHP, Ruby, Javascript and Python.

Answer (score 0):

Mine

.Net (3.5) - Visual studio 2008
.net 4 - visual studio 2010

flex - flash builder 4 / eclipse
Java - Eclipse

ROR - TextMate
HTML/CSS/JS etc - TextMate

Answer (score 0):

**C# / Mono** - I'd add MonoDevelop. Cross platform, so you have a C# IDE on Linux and Mac as well as Windows.

Comment: I was going to add MonoDevelop but I thought I heard that it had problems and couldn't compile against .NET?

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ - Visual Studio
C# - Visual Studio
Java - Depends. I use java mostly for mobiles, so, for example, Blackberry I use the Blackberry JDE, for any other J2ME mobile, Java ME SDK 3. I once used JCreator PRO to develop, one, when i didnt knew specified tools existed to code for mobiles, xDDDDD
JavaScript - Visual Studio, and that's cause i use mostly on my ASP.Net web applications
Visual Basic - 6.0 on MSVB6, .Net on Visual Studio (there's a software my companie bought and that was debeloped on 6; I was assigned to mantain and develope it further
PHP - DreamWeaver

Answer (score 0):

**XSLT** - XmlSpy, Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly freeware, but I'd use whats necessary.

- **C/C++ Win** — Visual Studio 2010
- **C/C++/Fortran Linux** —Netbeans
- **HTML/CSS** — Dreamweaver
- **Perl** — Activestate Komodo
- **PHP** — Activestate Komodo
- **Python** — Activestate Komodo
- **TCL** — Activestate Komodo

Answer (score 0):

If you're including Vim, then Notepad++. I use it for most languages, including Java (compiled with Ant) and smaller C++ projects (compiled with MinGW), and it seems to be pretty popular in general, especially for web development. It has more/better features than some of the more popular IDE's I've used, even. I do prefer using Visual Studio for C# and XCode for Objective-C, though.

Answer (score 0):

Smalltalk - your own image.

So Squeak uses Squeak, Pharo uses Pharo, ...

I think only Gnu Smalltalk doesn't, where I suspect they use Emacs or Vim.

Answer (score 0):

- **PHP/HTML/CSS** - [PHPEd](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phped.htm) Best php code completion out there.
- **C++** - [QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) w/ FakeVim (it's in the options)
- **Most Markup Languages** - [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (don't forget to add plugins)

Answer (score 0):

Does else anyone use **[Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/)** (**html**, **css**, **javascript**, **php**, **ruby**, **etc...)**?

I love that IDE and its got to be pretty popular with over six million downloads.

Answer (score 0):

For the marketplace that I work in currently, I've found this to be a roughly accurate breakdown of IDE usage.

PHP - Breaks down to about 1/3 Eclipse PDT, 2/3 Editplus/Notepad++. Oddly enough it's also the rough breakdown of what folks using OO coding practices as well.

Java - Mostly Eclipse. Netbeans has been slowly growing with newer coders with the latest release.

.Net - Visual Studio sweeps the field.

Perl - Eclipse EPIC (only one shop uses perl, and that's a one man operation so...)